# Windows command prompt strange behaviour on jq pipes

Tags: windows, command-line, jq

I'm trying to invoke command on jq using commandline (called as a subprocess). I encountered that the following:

```
jq -c ". | test(\"hmm|quack\")"
```

causes `The system cannot find the path specified`. It seems, that within an escaped string, `|` is interpreted as a pipe and executes what follows as a string. Yet without the symbol it behaves as it should.

Anyone knows what is the reason for this, and how to use the regex `|` ?

Comment: Consider using WSL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: As much as i enjoy a good joke, an advice of "Don't use windows" aint helpful.